# How can i update a mongodb field without having a single route for every individual field to be updated?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

here is my schema:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    phonenumber: {
        type: Number
    },
    fname: {
        type: String
    },
    lname: {
        type: String
    },
    role: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

This is express routes, routes/update.js. Each route updates a single a field for example when updating email or phone number.

```
//updating email.
app.post('/editemail', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function (err, users) {

        var email = req.body.email;
        users.update({
            email: email
        }, function (err, id) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("problem updating");
            } else {
                res.render("pages/profile", {
                    users: users
                });
            }
        })
    });
});

//Updating phonenumber
app.post('/editphone', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function (err, users) {
        var phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber;
        users.update({
            phonenumber: phonenumber,
        }, function (err, id) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("problem updating");
            } else {
                res.render("pages/profile", {
                    users: users
                });
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Is there a way that i can put all these routes into a single route and be able to update a single field independently?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way to approach this problem is to have a variable passed in with the req.body that indicates what you want to update. And then a switch statement in your route that updates according to what is sent in that variable.

Say you have a variable that you send from your frontend: `{type: 'email'}`

And then on the backend you have a switch statement inside your route:

**edit:**

```
app.post('/edit/:type', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
        // call with POST to PATH/edit/email
        switch(req.params.type) {
            case 'email':
                var email = req.body.email;
                user.email = email;
                user.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) res.send("problem updating");
                    res.render("pages/profile", {
                        user: user
                    });
                })
            // call with POST to PATH/edit/phonenumber
            case 'phonenumber':
            //....
```

or...

```
app.post('/edituser', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
        // call with POST to PATH/edituser with req.body.type === 'email'
        switch(req.body.type) {
            case 'email':
                var email = req.body.email;
                user.email = email;
                user.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) res.send("problem updating");
                    res.render("pages/profile", {
                        user: user
                    });
                })
            // call with POST to PATH/edituser with req.body.type === 'phonenumber'
            case 'phonenumber':
            //....
```

Put the logic for the update inside each case, and make sure you have a default: for when the api is hit without a `req.params.type` or `req.body.type` variable. Of course you could use an `if` `else if` etc... to do the same thing, but in this case imho a switch statement is a little more explicit.

[You can read more about switch statements here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

[You can read about mongoose models here.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)

Comment: Its aint working still. im getting a "Cannot read property 'update' of null".

Comment: have a look at my updated answer, sorry cut and paste your code without checking it, you should be using the `.findOne()` method to look up a single user.

Comment: I have no error now but it cant update. maybe im missing something ,check it out.

Comment: switch(req.body.type) {
          case 'email':
                var email = req.body.email;
              users.update({
                  email: email
              }, function (err, id) {
                if(err){
                  res.send("problem updating");
              }
              else{
                res.render("pages/profile",{users});
              }
              });
            break;

Comment: There are a number of ways to approach this, here is one. You could also find by id and update which is what I would recommend if you have the id.

Comment: Refactored slightly to use params rather than type in the body. How did you go with this?